# Jest stranspiles code differently then ts-node

Tags: import, jestjs, es6-modules, dayjs

I can't make my code work when running the project normally and running in Jest.

Running the project requires this kind of imports for dayjs:

```
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';
import * as utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import * as customParseFormat  from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';
```

**npm run dev (nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./src/app.ts):** No issues

**Jest:**  `TypeError: t is not a function`

Running the Jest tests requires this kind of imports for dayjs:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import customParseFormat  from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';
```

**npm run dev (nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./src/app.ts):**

```
dayjs.extend(utc);
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined`
```

**Jest:** Success!

So now it is impossible for me to write Tests. Why is it transpiled differntly?

Comment: The problem here is in how module interop was configured (a mismatch between `*` and default exports).

Answer (score 2):

In my case,

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

solved it.

Comment: You've saved my day man!

Comment: But it breaks PassportJS module.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to [ts-jest](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/) and it solved my problem. I was assuming that I could write JS tests to test the TS code but I suppose that is not possible.

Comment: You can write JS tests to test TS code. And Jest doesn't do anything on its own. It uses transpilers to transpile code. Babel is used by default, it can handle TS with a plugin, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-typescript . Any way, ts-jest is a better tool for this.